# how to "join" two tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I have two tables contains almost the same things. But they got datas from different sources, and in perfect world they are identical. Practicaly - they differs. The goal is to find matching records and connect each other, and then the umatched records are the result.

first_table:

id1, date1, value1

second_table:

id2, date2, value2

I create third table "joiner":

id1,id2

And now use this spell:

```
INSERT INTO joiner (SELECT id1,id2  FROM first_table,second_table WHERE value1=value2 and date1=date2 ORDER BY date1,date2,id1,id2);
```

(sorting is important, because sometimes some packages are missed, so i have to add it later)

And everything would be great, but... sometimes there are more than one record with the same value and date, and there's no way to identify it. The accepted solution is to join first from first_table with first from second_table, and second from first_table with second from second_table ,etc.

And here comes the problem.

Because the joiner has the unique keys on each column - the insert raises unique_violation error, because the example result is:

```
id1|id2
-------
 a1| b1
 a1| b2
 a2| b1
 a2| b2
```

If I use SELECT distinct id1,id2 of course nothing changes (a1,b1)!=(a1,b2)
If I use SELECT distinct on (id1) id1,id2 - the result sometimes is:

```
id1|id2
-------
 a1| b1
 a2| b1
```

I tried to use WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM first_table f WHERE f.id1<>first_table.id1) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM second_table s WHERE s.id2<>second_table.id2) - still nothing

I tried to add function with EXCEPTION, but this is also wrong - because it raises exception but joiner is still empty...

Any ideas?

**update**
I don't know why some people vote down for my question without any comment. Maybe because it is not enough clear - so especially for those example:

first_table:

```
id1, value1, date1

1,10, 2015-03-01
2,11, 2015-03-01
3,10, 2015-03-01
4,14, 2015-03-02
```

second_table:

```
id2, value2, date2

1,10, 2015-03-01
2,11, 2015-03-01
3,10, 2015-03-01
4,15, 2015-03-02
```

expected joiner

```
id1, id2

1,1
2,2
3,3
```

As you can see id1=4 and id2=4 doesn't have joiner - because value differs (auditor needs to manualy check and fix).

And there is a problem with id1=1 and id1=3 - are identical, so joiner without uniqness would looks like:

```
id1, id2

1,1
1,3
2,2
3,1
3,3
```

Which is wrong.

Comment: Sorting actually in the insert doesn't matter. It has only effect on the values that get inserted and since a table is just a collection of rows, the order doesn't matter. Unless you've omitted some parts.

Comment: IIUC, your goal is that the `joiner` table will contain all the *unique* rows from both `first_table` and `second_table` ? (that is: those only present in `one` + only present in `two` + present in both )

Comment: order is for select, not for insert. And is important - because item with id 10 should be before item 11 and without order it is undefined what order the insert will be.

Comment: It is no reason to add unique for both - if id1 is unique and id2 is unique the id1+id2 would be always unique.

Comment: Your goal is still not clear, at least to me. Maybe you could add some sample data and your intended result to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to use `row_number()` to enumerate the values for common date/value pairs in each table.

You query can be improved in other ways as well:

- When using `insert`, always list the columns.
- Learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  never use comma in the `from` clause.
- Use table aliases to specify where columns are coming from.

The query is:

```
INSERT INTO joiner(id1, id2)
    SELECT id1, id2
    FROM (select ft.*, row_number() over (partition by value1, date1 order by value1) as seqnum
          from first_table ft
         ) ft JOIN
         (select st.*, row_number() over (partition by value2, date2 order by value2) as seqnum
          from second_table st
         ) st
         ON ft.value1 = st.value2 and ft.date1 = st.date2 and ft.seqnum = st.seqnum
    ORDER BY ft.date1, st.date2, ft.id1, st.id2;
```

I don't think the `order by` is important, but I'm leaving it in because you think it is relevant.

Comment: O! I didn't know that JOIN (...) ON can be used with more than one condition - you are definetely right - I always use aaa JOIN bbb INSTEAD of aaa,bbb, but in this case I have to use more than one condition (value=value, date=date)

Comment: Runned, and looks ok-  no unique violations, the number of rows is quite good - now i have to check if it really do want I want